# get image original directory path when select from wp_media wordpress

Tags: wordpress

When i select an image, lets say from drive `D:/images/01.png` from `var custom_uploader = wp.media` I need this path `D:/images/01.png`.

when i select an image this functions trigger

```
add_action('add_attachment', 'auto_post_after_image_upload'); // Wordpress Hook
function auto_post_after_image_upload($attachId)
{
//get path here
`D:/images/01.png`
}
```

I need the inside this function. is it possible? the path should be the original path and not the `wp-content/uploads` directory path.

Comment: Modern browsers do not transfer the original client path during file uploads, for security/privacy reasons.